# How do we prove in general that $\lim_{t \to x} {t^a} = x^a$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How do we prove that for $a \in \mathbb{R}$,  $\lim_{t \to x} {t^a} = x^a$ in general using the epsilon/delta definition? My friend and I just spent an hour showing it for $t^{1/3}$, and the proof was very reliant on specific factoring and bounding a polynomial which I can see becoming highly nontrivial.

Comment: Also you can use induction .

Comment: How would you use induction on all real exponents?

Comment: If you want , I can write it.

Comment: Yes, please do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof that goes in many steps, some of which you may assume.

- Construct the exponential function
- Show this function is continuous and monotonic
- Conclude this function has an inverse (at least on its image), the logarithm
- Show that this inverse is continuous

Now we can take logarithms, and using continuity of the logarithm function, pass the limit outside. Then we may move the constant exponent down, pass it out of the limit, evaluate the limit, and then bring the constant back up. Now apply the exponential again, and you've proven it.